# DataList data in one Row

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to show the data from an DataList in one row. Here is a picture to show what I want to do https://www.dropbox.com/s/p7pcn67bt0304lo/pic.JPG

I use primefaces 4.0 and jsf 2.1

```
<p:dataTable id="sentTable" var="task" value="#{taskboxBean.taskboxSentList}" paginator="true"
            rows="5" selection="#{taskboxBean.selectedTaskbox}" selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{task.ID}"
            paginatorPosition="bottom" emptyMessage="">

            <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
                update=":contentForm, :postForm:tabViewPosts:trashTable,  :postForm:tabViewPosts:inboxTable, :postForm:tabViewPosts:sentTable"
                listener="#{taskboxBean.onTaskboxRowSelect}" />

            <p:column headerText="Post">

                <p:dataGrid var="task_to_user" value="#{task.TASKBOX_TO_USERS}" emptyMessage="Keine Daten">
                    <p:scrollPanel>
                        <p:outputLabel
                            value="#{task_to_user.USER.FIRST_NAME} #{task_to_user.USER.LAST_NAME} #{task_to_user.USER.EMAIL}" />
                    </p:scrollPanel>
                </p:dataGrid>
                <h:outputText value="#{task.TASKTYPE.NAME}" />
                <br />
                <h:outputText value="#{task.CREATE_TIMESTAMP}" />
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

try This

```
<p:dataGrid  var="task_to_user" value="#{task.TASKBOX_TO_USERS}" emptyMessage="Keine Daten" rows="1" />
```

Assigning 1 row only

Comment: put it inside a panelGrip with column 1